# Hide groupIndicator of expandable listview based on listview positions

Tags: java, android

```
<ExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
android:background="#ffffff"
/>
```

I have used an expandable list view with group Indicator...
if in list view fourth position, there is no child for a group ...then it should not show the indicator in fourth position ...how to go with it

Answer (score 2):

Try to set android:groupIndicator attribute of ExpandableListView a null value or transparent color.
Something like `android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = newGroupView(isExpanded, parent);

            ImageView inidicatorImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.explist_indicator);

            if( groupPosition == 4 ) {
                inidicatorImage .setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            } else {
                inidicatorImage .setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            }


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: i dont get GropViewHolder in my code...from which class ur importing

Comment: The method newGroupView(boolean, ViewGroup) is undefined for the type Main_Screen.ExpAdapter....also i dont use any ImageVIew for indicator....using inbulit ExpandableListView

Answer (score 0):

In yourAdapter -> getGroupView() set the visibility of the indicator image to invisible...

I did this thru custom adapter and setting my own indicator image....

Comment: get me an example ..how to hide in fourth position